# Is the telecom carrier notified when a SIM card is used on a device different from the original device?

Tags: mobile

I have two phones, both unlocked, and I'm curious if the carrier receives some kind of info or notification that the SIM card has switched devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IMEI number (which is unique to a phone) is transmitted every time your phone registers in a new cell. That happens every time, your phone connects to a new cell tower. All of this data is submitted to your carrier. This means, that your carrier will know, if and when you use your SIM card in different devices.

Comment: Thanks! I had that assumption, so thanks for confirming it.